# Why does this xpath work but the css selection doesn't [locator not found] for a UL

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, selenium, rspec

I'm working on switching from xpath to css for my selectors where possible.

This worked in xpath:

```
//ul[contains(@id,'district-switcher')]
```

but what I thought was the equivalent in css:

```
css=ul#district_switcher
```

just gives locator not found.  I'm not using contains for the css as I don't think I should need to

I am using the firefox selenium IDE

HTML:

```
<ul id="district-switcher" class="nav nav-pills" style="background-color:
transparent;"><li class="dropdown open"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
Change district
<b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>...
```

What am I doing wrong with the css= selector approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the `css=` part, but you wrote `district_switcher`.  It used to be `district-switcher`.  More accurately it would be `ul[id*=district-switcher]`

Comment: Why the ID* for an exact match? (just curious)

Comment: I think your answer was first.  Will accept soon when I can (SO time limit)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant `id*=` works like `contains` does.  Just `#district-switcher` is probably the most desirable.  `ul#district-switcher` doesn't make sense unless there is some thought that there could be other elements with that ID which is a red flag.

Comment: I think ul#district-switcher makes a lot of sense actually. It's a clue for whoever's reading the code to know what kind of element #district-switcher is and it only costs 2 chars.

Answer (score 2):

Simple typo: `#district_switcher` is not the same as `#district-switcher`.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS equivalent to `//ul[contains(@id,'district-switcher')]` is:

```
ul#district-switcher
```

For instance:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<ul id="district-switcher" class="nav nav-pills" style="background-color:
transparent;"><li class="dropdown open"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
Change district
<b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>
EOT

doc.at('ul#district-switcher')['class'] # => "nav nav-pills"
doc.at('ul#district-switcher a').text # => "\nChange district\n"
```

Nokogiri supports [jQuery's CSS selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), which makes it a pretty robust way of navigating through HTML *AND* XML documents.

Comment: Thanks for the CSS selectors link,I was searching this link since long past and also told you to share. Now today at last you did. :)

Comment: @Priti, It's not my responsibility to tell you where to find things; It's sufficient for me to say things exist. It's your task, as the learner, to search and find. The jQuery document is only one of many that describe "CSS selectors". If you had searched for that string you would have found what you wanted many times over. A subsequent search for "jquery selectors" would have given you some additional ones specific to jQuery. Either way you would have been way ahead.

Comment: @theTinMan please don't be angry. I am thankful that you have given the link here.And it is helpful.